Basic illustration of universal computation in Margenstern's work on Cellular Automata in Hyperbolic Spaces
I am fascinated with these two hyperbolic tessellations, what Maurice Margenstern calls the heptagrid and the pentagrid.

I have the two volumes/books he authored, but they are a bit dense for my not-so-very-mathematical mind (but I'm good with software/code). ChatGPT said about universal computation related to that:

Margenstern showed that cellular automata on the pentagrid could simulate various computational processes, including universal computation. This means that these automata can perform any computation that a Turing machine can, highlighting the computational power of cellular automata in hyperbolic spaces.

What "power" is being alluded to here?
Can you briefly explain how the computation works, and hint at its efficiency/relationships compared to regular modern computers, from a more computer-science/software and less mathematical perspective?
I read about and started taking some basic notes on their description of the Railway Model of computation, but that is like for an individual bit of information. He has a few diagrams floating around of basic logic gates implemented with probably dozens of railway units. But what would it look like in terms of the tessellation if there were millions of railway units? How does the computation flow around on the tessellation, generally speaking? How does it work basically, at a high level?
